# Test iPhone 4s hardware without battery. Possible?

Tags: hardware, battery, iphone

So, I have this iPhone 4s, which was broken. So i replaced the screen. While I was replacing it, I accidentally broke the black wire that connects the battery to the motherboard. So I dont know if it works, and I dont want to spend money on new battery if the screen doesn't work. I also want to test the motherboard, since I replaced the screen because the old one showed blue vertical lines. So I need to be sure both screen and motherboard is functioning. Can you test it somehow without battery?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Even with the battery disconnected you will be able to test the iPhone as long as it's plugged into the wall. I repair Apple products professionally and I am **positive** that it is possible, having tested an iPhone 4s this way just last week.

[image]
Using a mirror, that's about as good as I can get proving this with a photo.

[image]
Test the old screen like this

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37598/discussion-on-answer-by-redeagle2000-test-iphone-4s-hardware-without-battery-po).