# Test iPhone SE without a battery. Possible?

Tags: iphone

In this thread, apparently you can test a iPhone without a battery.

[Test iPhone 4s hardware without battery. Possible?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/232666/test-iphone-4s-hardware-without-battery-possible)

What about iPhone SE? Is it possible to check if the mainboard and screen is working by disconnecting the battery and then connecting the lightning cable to the mains?

The reason I wnt to do is to check if the lightning connector pins are damaged. By applying 3.8 V directly on the pins where the battery would have been connected and then pressing the power button, the phone booted up ( I see a current fluctuation between 0.15 and 0.72 A on the multimeter ) . But if I do try to power on the device just with the lightning connector, it doesnt. So, if it is possible technically to boot an iphone SE without a battery, then the connectors are damaged.

Comment: Just curious - why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Andre edited with an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

The battery is required to boot the device. Once it has booted, you can leave the Lightning cable connected and then disconnect the battery.

Comment: FWIW, I was changing a battery on a 6S, and supplied ~4V to see if everything was alright before attaching the new battery. It did not boot. The new battery was ~4V. When I attached it, the 6S booted just fine. @infoclogged is probably correct. There must be a magical chip in those phones, I have no idea how it can tell the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I don’t see why it wouldn’t work on a iPhone SE if it works on other phones. Just make sure you don’t unplug it or else it will shut off right away as there will be no battery to power it.

Comment: Apple makes complicated hardware. And they cheat. They just copped to deliberately slowing down older iPhones to push new products. And Jobs ordered his engineers to use secret apple-screws back in the day. These nazi hippies really will do anything to prevent a user from playing with his hardware.

Comment: @user2497 LOL!  That was hilarious.